# How to Convert Array to Params of Method?

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, method-parameters

I need to pass **params** (like: `'param1', 'param2', 'param3'`) to the method... but I have array of params (like: `array('param1', 'param2', 'param3')`). How to convert array to params?

```
function foo(array $params) {

    bar(
        // Here should be inserted params not array.
    );

}
```

Comment: When you pass the $params array will you know the param names?

Comment: @Adrian, yes. Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

For example:

```
call_user_func_array('bar', $params);
```

Comment: I tried like [this](http://pastie.org/2158401), but it gives me [an error](http://pastie.org/2158405).

Comment: I think you passed a string for $data.

Comment: Nope. `list_users(array('username', 'email'), 10, 0);`

Comment: But you call with `call_use_func_array` the function `list_users` with the parameters 'username' and 'email'. But your function requires an array, an integer and again an integer.

So the $data array must contain the parameters of the list_users function.

Comment: In case you wanted to call method of a class use it this way
`call_user_func_array([$instanceOfClass, "method"], $params);`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the param names you could to the following

```
$params = array(
    'param1' => 'value 1',
    'param2' => 'value 2',
    'param3' => 'value 3',
);

function foo(array $someParams) {
    extract($someParams);  // this will create variables based on the keys

    bar($param1,$param2,$param3);
}
```

Not sure if this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert one to the other like this:

```
function foo(array $params)
{
    bar(...$params);
}
```

or go straight to bar:

```
bar(...$array);
```

For the "bar" function to receive several parameters you can use:

```
function bar(...$params)
{
    //$params is a array of parameters
}
```

or

```
function bar($p1, $p2, $p3)
{
    //$pn is a variables
}
```

or

```
function bar($p1, ...$pn)
{
    //$p1 is a variable
    //$pn is a array of parameters
}
```

but a lot of attention with the types and quantity of parameters to not give you problems.

visite: [Function Arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)